# Adjunction formula for non compact surfaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, mg.metric-geometry, divisors

Let $M$ be a non compact complex surface and S an embedded compact Riemann surface in $M$.

I already know how to show the following equality of fiber bundle:

$$\Omega^2_{M}|S =\Omega^1_S \otimes N^*_S$$
where $\Omega^2_{M}|S$ is the canonical vector bundle of $M$ restricted to $S$ and $\Omega^1_S$ is the canonical vector bundle of $S$ and $N^*_S$

is the dual of the normal vector bundle of $S$ over $M$.

Question : is it possible to deduce from this formula the following :
$$K_M.S + S^2 = 2g-2$$
in term of intersection multiplicity of divisors and $g$

denotes the genus of S.

i konwI know this formula is correct when $M$

is compact and it is known as the adjunction formula but iI don't know for the non compact-compact case.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you look at the proof in the compact case and try to generalize it?

Comment: How do you define intersection numbers when $M$ is not compact?

Comment: I looked for the proof when $M$ is compact, but i don't know how to generalize it since i don't even know if the intersection number is well defined, and even because i think the degree of a 2-form is not well defined, but i fount in many papers wich talks about such results for resolurion of singularities which are not compact spaces see page 4 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/0911.5090.pdf  he says '' here exists a unique divisor with rational oefficients $Z_can$ supported by E such that $Z_can·E_i=K_{\tilde{X}}.E_i$, for all $i∈V(\Gamma)$ ''

Comment: If the compact S has no boundary, intersection numbers make sense. (Otherwise in certain settings there is a relative adjunction formula.)

Comment: yes i want $S$ to be a compact Riemann surface with no boundary, it would help me a lot if you could show me at least why it does make sense to do this intersection ( $K_X . S $ )and in the ideal case can you give a book which talks about those things, because all  i find is about the algebraic case and never for any non complex manifold

Comment: in many references they define the  canonical divisor for a resolution of normal surface  singularity to be divisor the divisor of a global meromorphic two form.  why is it possible to do so since a resolution of singularity is not a compact complex surface and they proove the adjunction formula (see for example https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjmjIr48orwAhUUCGMBHQa8CIkQFjABegQIBBAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fusers.renyi.hu%2F~nemethi%2FJEGYZET.ps&usg=AOvVaw0Gk4o4UfYwR2ALKa8a-lna  page 21 )

Comment: for a more precise question i would to understand the end of the proof of the adjunction formula in this paper https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjmjIr48orwAhUUCGMBHQa8CIkQFjABegQIBBAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fusers.renyi.hu%2F~nemethi%2FJEGYZET.ps&usg=AOvVaw0Gk4o4UfYwR2ALKa8a-lna  page 21  2.25